# Замена дублирующих значений в словаре из списка значений

Tags: python-3.x, словари

Есть словарь и список. Словарь и список вводятся с клавиатуры. Необходимо в словаре найти одинаковые значения и заменить их на новые значения из списка в порядке их следования в списке.

Например:

```
D = {'1': 'k', '2': 'u', '3': 'k', '4': 'u'}
list = ['m', 'n', 'd', 'r']
```

Вывод:

```
D = {'1': 'k', '2': 'u', '3': 'm', '4': 'n'}
```

Comment: покажите что вы уже попробовали и что у вас не получается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
D = {}
print('Ввод словаря:')
while True:
    k = input('key: ')
    if k == 'exit':
        break
    v = input('value: ')
    D[k] = v

repeat = list(set(D.values()))

print()
print('Ввод списка замен:')
length = len(D) - len(repeat)
if length > 0:
    print('(символов для замены нужно минимум {0:d})'.format(length))

L = []
while True:
    r = input('символ замены: ')
    if r == 'exit':
        break
    L.append(r)

for k in sorted(D.keys()):
    if D[k] in repeat:
        repeat.pop(repeat.index(D[k]))
    else:
        try:
            D[k] = L.pop(0)
        except IndexError:
            print('\tВарианты замен закончились!')
            break
print(D)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогли!

Comment: @Ярослав тогда отметьте ответ галочкой.

Answer (score 1):

Опишу алгоритм псевдокодом:

```
# запомним номер следующего элемента из списка, который будем подставлять
счетчик = 0
# создадим пустое множество, в которое будем добавлять ключи из словаря
# для подсчета повторов
повторы = пустое множество

# переберем только ключи из словаря
для каждого ключа из словаря:
    если повторы не содержат ключ:
        добавить ключ в повторы
    иначе: # ключ уже встречался
        словарь[ключ] = список_для_подстановки[счетчик]
        счетчик увеличить на 1
```

Остается открытым вопрос: а что, если списка не хватит для подстановки? Например, в списке 2 элемента, а в словаре три случая повтора ключа.

Comment: Предполагается, что список содержит намного больше элементов, чем словарь.